# Calling external methods without instantiating an object

Tags: java, object, instantiation

I was wondering if it was possible to call the methods of an external class without actually having to declare an object of that class. They way I've got it set up causes the ArrayList stored within the object empties every time the method the object is used in is called.

If I can call the method without an object, then I can fix my problem.

Thanks in advance.

calling class:

```
 public class BookingScreen extends Activity {

    GAClass sendApplication = new GAClass();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking_screen);
    }

    public void saveBookingInfo(View view) {

        EditText applicantNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.applicantNameTextField);
        EditText itemToBurnText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemToBurnTextField);

        String appName = applicantNameText.getText().toString();
        String appItemToBurn = itemToBurnText.getText().toString();

        if (appItemToBurn.isEmpty() || appName.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(BookingScreen.this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            sendApplication.storeApplication(appName, appItemToBurn);
            this.finish();
        }
   }
```

External method class:

```
     public class GAClass {

    ArrayList<Application> peopleAttending;


    public void storeApplication(String name, String item){
        peopleAttending = new ArrayList<>(10);
        peopleAttending.add(new Application(name, item));

   }
  }
```

Comment: Declare method as static. Static method can be used without object instantiation

Comment: want to see what you've tried

Comment: The calling method or the external method?

Comment: What exactly is an "external class"?

Comment: After  reading your requirement you can if you make your variable  ArrayList<Application> peopleAttending  as  static final can resolve your issue!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static methods. You can call a static method without creating object of enclosing class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Please mark as answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like below

```
public class GAClass {

    public static ArrayList<Application> peopleAttending=null;


    public static void storeApplication(String name, String item){
        if(null==peopleAttending){
          peopleAttending = new ArrayList();
        }
        peopleAttending.add(new Application(name, item));

   }
  }
```

You can invoke above method like below

```
 GAClass.storeApplication(str_name,str_item);
```

when you make peopleAttending arraylist static it can be access in static method and

```
if(null==peopleAttending){
              peopleAttending = new ArrayList();
            }
```

Above code ensure first time initialization if peopleAttending 9s null

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
The `static` methods in a class would not need an instance of the class so you can make the methods you need (that do not require the state of the object - i.e. do not need a particular object to work on) `static` and call them like this:

`ClassWithStaticMethods.staticMethod() ;`